# ERD UML advice (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, uml, erd

I am having trouble with producing a ERD model using UML for a piece of work regarding an attendance monitoring system in Universities.

The entities I have are:

```
Student
Course
Module
Grade
Class
Attendance Log
```

Please could anyone help to improve it?

See draft ERD for basic understanding -->

[image]

Comment: Looks like your multiplicities are incorrect. E.g., a Student only takes one Course?

Answer (score 0):

This is just opinion, so take it for what it is:

- Is there a relationship between Module and Course? Doesn't a Course comprise Modules?
- You have identifiers for Primary Key (PK) which is an RDBMS concept rather than UML Class models. You might want instead to stereotype your identity attributes as `<<unique>>`.
- If you are producing an ERDs (as opposed to a UML Class model) then you might want to consider how you will resolve the many-to-many relationships. Clearly m2m is not a structure that RDBMS can manage without having some sort of join entity.
- Attendance Log may be better named as a Student Class Attendance. I assume this is there to record which Students attended which Classes, so it's a join entity.

I would recommend reading Eric Evan's "Domain Driven Design", this might help identify the main entities, their satellites and how they relate.